# Specify a format to store data in rabbitMQ message queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue, system-design

I am using RabbitMQ as message broker and Celery as task queue to process my queue content. Lets take a basic example where we want to add two numbers x and y.

I have created the shared task as :

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I see when I am pushing the content to the queue, the data is stored as

[image: [[5, 5], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]]

```
(myprojectenv) root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-02:/etc/myproject# python manage.py shell
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from myproject.tasks import add
>>> add.delay(5, 5)
<AsyncResult: 88f4d5c2-f68a-42c1-acda-d64593df1899>
```

But instead I would like my data to be stored in a different format like

```
{operation : 'add', listOfNumbers : [5, 5]}
```

How can I change the way in which my data is actually getting pushed into the queue? While fetching the same I can get the dictionary and unpack the values and process the same

Comment: What you are trying to do makes no sense. That format is internal, specific to Celery. Any change will result in Celery workers not being able to execute tasks. If you want to write some tool that processes what is in RabbitMQ, you need to learn how Celery/Kombu serializes tasks using JSON format (other formats are possible too, like my favourite MsgPack for an example).

Comment: So in what format is it storing data? Always a list format? And what exactly it will be receiving will be specified by the type of function definition of shared task? Is it?

Comment: You need to dig into Celery/Kombu source code to find out how they JSON-serialize tasks... People actually do not need to know this, that is why Celery guys did not put anything about it in Celery docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "task": "myapp.tasks.add",
    "id": "54086c5e-6193-4575-8308-dbab76798756",
    "args": [4, 4],
    "kwargs": {}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33809572)